# Search with multiple JOIN-table atrributes

Tags: filemaker

I'm an absolute FM newbee. I managed to create an address database and build up a tag table which I connected via a join table to the addresses. So far so good. Now I want to create a search form with multiple drop-down menus to select some tags and search for addresses that are are assigned to them.

The problem is, that when I create multiple drop-down fields that are connected to this relationship, they seem all to be "in sync". Means that when I change one field, all the others are changed as well. Can anybody give me a hint how I can do this?

The next step would be to choose between && and || in the search.

Thx
Dan

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like they are in sync because you are just creating multiple fields that are showing the same relationship. You might try doing it another way. Maybe have a portal that displays the list of tags and have check boxes to flag the tags in the portal you want to search for.